# Inserting current date into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I want to insert the current date into the table from my php page but i don't know how to do so. I would also like to know if i am constructing the table right wrt the data type being used. Its a normal "date" data type. Thank you!!

Comment: Assuming you're using MySQL?

Comment: Based on their other questions I assumed so

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a variety of ways like:

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename (datecolname) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE)
INSERT INTO tablename (datecolname) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE())
INSERT INTO tablename (datecolname) VALUES (NOW())
INSERT INTO tablename (datecolname) VALUES (CUR_DATE())
INSERT INTO tablename (datecolname) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
INSERT INTO tablename (datecolname) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

See [Mysql's Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for more

Comment: I can think of a few more, but I think that's enough, @JohnConde

Comment: hello, thanks for the response but it is not working from the php page.. it is working directly in mysql.

Comment: $sql2 = "INSERT into requisitionreceipt (RequisitionID, ReceivedBy, DateReceived)
VALUES ('$RequisitionID', '$_SESSION['StaffID']', (curdate()))";

Comment: I think i need to review the session validation... i know this seems simple but i am very new to php

Comment: Get rid of the parenthesis around `curdate()`

Comment: Hello again.. I got it... it was indeed the session... thanks for all the advice.. i really appreciate it... @John Conde ... we need more persons like you who will help a complete strangers for nothing in return.. keep good.. thanks again :D